NPM fails on Jenkins only with deprecated dependencies and missing login
We have a .Net 8 solution that includes an Angular 18 project built in Visual Studio 2022. It builds and publishes on my local development environment but when trying to build it via our Jenkins server, it fails with deprecated warnings of packages I have never heard of and also needing a NPM login. We have various other .Net + Angular builds in Jenkins that build successfully, daily. Those are still on older versions of Angular and running on older versions of NPM. With a "NVM use" step in this build, we set it to NPM 20.14, the same I use on my local dev machine.
Here is the relevant Jenkins output:

C:\Git-Dev\IAS\IasAddOns\IasAddOns.Server>dotnet publish -c Release -o PreCompiled -r linux-x64
Determining projects to restore...
Restored C:\Git-Dev\IAS\IasAddOns\IasAddOns.Server\IasAddOns.Server.csproj (in 702 ms).
v20.14.0
Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes...
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated rimraf@2.6.3: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm error code E401
npm error Incorrect or missing password.
npm error If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm error authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm error that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm error Please try again, or recover your password at:
EXEC : npm error https: //www.npmjs.com/forgot [C:\Git-Dev\IAS\IasAddOns\iasaddons.client\iasaddons.client.esproj]
npm error
npm error If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm error probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm error     npm login
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-08-14T17_52_56_247Z-debug-0.log
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.javascript.sdk\1.0.784122\Sdk\Sdk.targets(251,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 1. [C:\Git-Dev\IAS\IasAddOns\iasaddons.client\iasaddons.client.esproj]

This is the package.json file for the Angular build:
{
  "name": "iasaddons.client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "run-script-os",
    "prebuild": "node set-build-info.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run prebuild && ng build --configuration production",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "prestart": "node aspnetcore-https",
    "start:windows": "ng serve --ssl --ssl-cert \"%APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem\" --ssl-key \"%APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key\" --host=127.0.0.1",
    "start:default": "ng serve --ssl --ssl-cert \"$HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.pem\" --ssl-key \"$HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.key\" --host=127.0.0.1",
    "explore-source-maps": "source-map-explorer dist/iasaddons.client/**/*.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^18.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^18.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^18.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^18.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^18.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^18.0.3",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.15.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^13.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "run-script-os": "*",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.3",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}

Where do the dependencies of the inflight, rimraf and glob packages come from? They are not in my package.json file and I do not see these warnings when building locally.
Why is it needing a NPM login? None of our other jobs do. Is this new the NPM 20.14?
Please let me know if I can supply any further info to help solve this.
I tried adding extra logging in the package.json file but don't see any additional logging in Jenkins. I'm not sure the dotnet publish command uses that build script from package.json?
When running npm ls rimraf to see where it comes from, I get this:

+-- rimraf@3.0.2 extraneous
+-- temp@0.9.4 extraneous | -- rimraf@2.6.3 extraneous -- webpack-dev-server@ extraneous   `-- rimraf@ extraneous

So is webpack to culprit? How do I get it to use an up to date version of rimraf?
Is it perhaps related to how Visual Studio sets up the build commands that get fed into Jenkins via the dotnet publish command?

Those dependencies come from third party packages, check your package-lock.json and you will find them. You can override them in your devDependencies using a non conflict version, if there is not one (for example inflight) you can try some nasty "solutions"...Create a folder "overrides", add the conflicted package (download it from npm), change the version in the package.json of the conflicted package  (for example inflight@1.0.6 to inflight@1.0.10) and override it in your package.json "devDependencies" {"inflight": "file:overrides/inflight"}. i do not post it as a solutions bc is not one.
